# Narrow bandpass filtering

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, bandpass, decomposition

I want to plot a specific frequency (e.g., 1 kHz or 100 Hz) of an audio file (sampling rate 44.1 kHz). I have done fft and spectrogram analysis on the file, but I am now interested in plotting only one frequency (as a sine wave) of the signal versus time. Here is also an example signal I created with only two frequencies and tried to pass only one of them, but I failed.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, freqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bandpass_filter(signal, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyquist = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyquist
    high = highcut / nyquist
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    w, h = freqz(b, a, fs=fs)
    filtered_signal = np.convolve(signal, b / a, mode='same')
    return filtered_signal, w, h

# Example usage
fs = 44100  # Sample rate of the signal
f0 = 5   # Desired frequency to pass
lowcut = f0 - 1  # Lower cutoff frequency
highcut = f0 + 1 # Upper cutoff frequency

# Generate example signal
t = np.linspace(0, 1, num=fs, endpoint=False)
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 5 * t) +  np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10 * t) # Signal with noise

t = t[:44100]
signal = signal[:44100]

# Apply bandpass filter
filtered_signal, w, h = bandpass_filter(signal, lowcut, highcut, fs)

# Plot original signal, filtered signal, and frequency response of the filter
#plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12), nrows=4, ncols=1, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.5, 'wspace': 2})
plt.subplot(4, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, signal)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Original Signal')

plt.subplot(4, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, filtered_signal)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Filtered Signal')

plt.subplot(4, 1, 3)
plt.plot(w, np.abs(h))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.title('Frequency Response of the Bandpass Filter')

plt.subplot(4, 1, 4)
plt.plot(t, signal-filtered_signal)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.title('Specific signal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you know what band-pass filters are?

Comment: Hi Jdip. Yes, I have created one. Here is a code that I have for the bandpass. The signal I generated only has two frequencies (5 Hz, and 10 Hz), and I set the high and low cuts to 5+1 and 5-1 to only allow the 5Hz pass. But the filtered signal amplitude is in the order of 1e-21. What I expected was to see a sin wave with a frequency of 5 Hz for the passed signal and 10 Hz for the blocked signal. I added the code to the question!

Comment: Chances are high that the filter frequency doesn't match the signal frequency due to some kind of unit confusion, although it doesn't jump out at me

Comment: There's a lot going on here. When I have time I'll try and provide a detailed answer.  Start off with something easier. For now, try with sines at frequencies 2000 and 3000 (and cut-off 1600 and 2400). Your filter requirements are too stringent for such low frequencies and fs = 44100

Comment: I've written up something. Let me know once you've tried (do option 1 first) if you have more questions or if anything is un-clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the very low pass-band amplitude of your filter. You're trying to implement a Butterworth band-pass filter with bandwidth $\texttt{BW} = 2 \texttt{Hz}$ at a sampling frequency $f_s = 44100 \texttt{Hz}$. That's a $\texttt{BW}/f_s$ ratio of $\approx 0.00005$, which is too stringent on your order-5 Butterworth filter.

To be a little more general than your use-case (for which you could simply reduce $f_s$ drastically and use a low-pass filter), **I'll assume we have a real-world signal with large bandwidth and we're trying to isolate one component** (which we'll keep at $5 \texttt{Hz}$).

There are a few options here, I'll go through 2 of them, I'll leave the coding to you for option 2.

#### Option 1: High order FIR

Easiest if you're not worried about processing time and want to keep your parameters as is, simply use a high-order [FIR filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html#scipy.signal.firwin):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import freqz, firwin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bandpass_filter(signal, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=20000):
    nyquist = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyquist
    high = highcut / nyquist
    b = firwin(order, [low, high], pass_zero=False)
    w, h = freqz(b, 1, worN=2*fs, fs=fs)
    filtered_signal = np.convolve(signal, b, mode='same')
    return filtered_signal, w, h

# Example usage
fs = 44100  # Sample rate of the signal
f0 = 5   # Desired frequency to pass
f1 = 10
lowcut = f0 - 1  # Lower cutoff frequency
highcut = f0 + 1 # Upper cutoff frequency

# Generate example signal
t = np.linspace(0, 1, num=fs, endpoint=False)
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * t) +  np.sin(2 * np.pi * f1 * t) 

# Apply bandpass filter
filtered_signal, w, h = bandpass_filter(signal, lowcut, highcut, fs)

# Plot frequency response of the filter
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(w, np.abs(h))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.title('Frequency Response of the Bandpass Filter')
plt.show()
```

#### Option 2: [Decimate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.decimate.html) then filter

One way to increase our $\texttt{BW}/f_s$ ratio is to decrease $f_s$ (and/or increase $\texttt{BW}$ of course), which in our case we can do since our signal's frequency component of interest sits at $5 \texttt{Hz}$ (remember the Nyquist rule $f_s \geq 2f_{\texttt{max}}$).
Choose $f_s = 100 \texttt{Hz}$ and $\texttt{BW} = 0.1\texttt{Hz}$ for example, increasing $\texttt{BW}/f_s$ to $0.001$.
We can then easily use either a lower-order FIR (see option 1 link for design) or IIR filter (I suggest you take a look at Robert Bristow-Johnson's [Audio EQ Cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/) if you go the IIR route, *look for the BPF section*).

If you go with this option, **do not forget to low-pass your signal before down-sampling, otherwise you'll get aliasing**. Follow the link provided above for a decimation function that takes care of that for you.
(*for your specific use-case, since your signal's highest component is at $10\texttt{Hz}$, you don't need to low-pass filter, you can simply set $f_s$ somewhere above $20\texttt{Hz}$*).

#### Remarks

- A second order IIR such as one designed using the cookbook can work with your $f_s$ as is, I’d reduce the passband bandwidth $\texttt{BW}$ though.
- For IIR filtering, I would use [`filtfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html#scipy.signal.filtfilt)

Comment: Many thanks for your time. I tried the first option, and it works fine on low frequencies. But When I go to audio frequencies (44100 Hz), everything masses up, even if I set taps to 1001.

Comment: What do you mean if you go to “audio frequencies”? What frequency are you trying to isolate? Please edit your question by adding the problem you’re facing now.

Comment: I vote for option 2! Nice work

Comment: @DanBoschen That's where I would go to also, but for someone starting off in DSP, I thought I'd mention an easier path as well...

Comment: Thanks for your good answer @Jdip. I have audio data, and I am trying to isolate only one frequency (e.g., 1 kHz). I tried your option 1, and it works beautifully for more straightforward single-frequency audio signals (100 Hz + 250 Hz, blocking 100 Hz). But when I try the real audio file and I change the ban-pass frequency, the passed signal shape does not change.

Comment: @pbena Let's continue in a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145324/narrow-band-filtering)